# Applications of isotropic quadratic forms

Tags: examples, quadratic-forms, teaching

I will soon be teaching an introductory course on bilinear algebra and quadratic forms. I will likely spend most of the time and effort on positive definite quadratic forms and euclidean spaces. These have nice and concrete (i.e. not to theoretical physics) applications since they are basic for many optimisation problems. Are there any applications of this type (so not Einstein's relativity theory) which involve isotropic forms (and which hopefully would be useful beyond just motivating the material for bored undergraduates, e.g. that would be a basis for a problem or a series of exercises)?

Comment: "Isotropic" = forms that represent zero?  Sure; they often arise as intersection forms on algebraic surfaces (e.g. an elliptic fibration yields a nontrivial divisor with self-intersection zero), and are often useful  to describe the structure of positive-definite forms (quite a few examples in Conway and Sloane's "SPLAG" = *Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups").

Comment: also (and possibly more suitable for undergraduates) the determinant of a 2-by-2 matrix, and trace(A^2) for square matrices of any order, are  natural quadratic forms that represent zero.  And a conic plane curve is basically a quadratic form in 3 real variables that represents zero (up to multiplying the form by a nonzero scalar).  If it has rational coefficients then the existence of rational points is equivalent to the question of whether the form represents zero nontrivially over the rationals.

Comment: Made CW according to the OP's wishes (people are encouraged to tweak or extend or correct it).

Comment: Isotropic forms are easy and fun to deal with over finite fields. And you might connect the particular case of $U_4(\mathbb{F}_2)$ to 27 lines on  cubic  surfaces...

Answer (score 4):

I've enjoyed finding out how to parametrize the integer null vectors of an indefinite ternary with integer coefficients. The observation that an isotropic ternary integrally represents an integer multiple of $y^2 - zx$ goes back to Fricke and Klein (1897 I think).

It is easy to find all ration vectors in the null cone. However, it is fairly difficult to pull out all the primitive integer vectors. If we just multiply through by a denominator (in symbols) from stereographic projection, we typically miss a fixed fraction of solutions.

All told, the outcome is that the integer null vectors are parametrized by a finite number of Pythagorean Triple type formulas, but not necessarily just one.

why not...

This is about ternary quadratic forms with integer coefficients. We use the ordering in
 http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Lehman_1992.pdf  and
 http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Watson_Representation_1954.pdf 
I like how Watson writes it, writing $zx$ instead of $xz.$ The ordered sextuple
$$ \langle a,b,c, r,s,t \rangle $$ refers to the form
$$ f(x,y,z) = a x^2 + b y^2 + c y^2 + r y z + s z x + t x y  $$
The Hessian matrix, of second partial derivatives, is

$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 a & t & s \\
t & 2b & r \\
s & r & 2c
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The discriminant is half the determinant of $H$ and therefore an integer,
$$  \Delta = 4abc + rst - a r^2 - b s^2 - c t^2. $$

Oh, right. Given a column vector 
$$
U = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right),
$$
we have
$$  f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2} \; \;  U^T H U. $$

We will say that $f$ represents another form $g,$ with Hessian $G,$ if there is an integer matrix $P$ with $\det P \neq 0,$ such that
$$  P^T H P = G. $$ Note that $ \det G = \det H \left( \det P \right)^2$  is still nonzero.

Suppose that $f$ is isotropic over the integers. This means that there is some $(u_1, u_2, u_3),$ not all zero, with  $f(u_1, u_2, u_3)= 0.$

Theorem: if $f$ is isotropic with nonzero discriminant, then there is a nonzero integer $n$ such that $f$ represents $n (y^2 - zx).$

It took me three steps to prove this, so I will present it that way. The first statement of this that I know is pages 507-508 of 
[Fricke Klein](https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen%20%C3%BCber%20die%20Theorie%20der%20automorphen%20%20Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false) 
This is also on page 303 of [Cassels](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html)
but is not part of the online preview.

First, we have 
$$
U = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The hypothesis is that
$$  U^T H U = 0. $$
On the other hand, we are told that the determinant of $H$ is nonzero, which tells us that $HU \neq \vec{0}.$ It follow that there is a nonzero integer vector 
$$
V = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
such that
$$ V^T H U = 0. $$
For example, using the ordinary cross product, we could simply use $V = (HU) \times U.$

We may take any third vector as the final column of a matrix

$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
u_1 & v_1 & w_1 \\
u_2 & v_2 & w_2 \\
u_3 & v_3 & w_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
as long as the determinant is nonzero.  The outcome is that, with some integers $i,j,k,l,$
$$
P^T H P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & l \\
0 & 2i & j \\
l & j & 2k
\end{array}
\right).
$$
That is, $f$ represents 
$$ \langle 0,i,k,j,l,0 \rangle $$

Next, we take a new matrix
$$
Q = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & j^2 - 4ik \\
0 & 1 & -2jl \\
0 & 0 & 4il
\end{array}
\right).
$$
It took me a long time to find $Q.$ We now have, with some nonzero integers $m,n,$
$$
Q^T P^T H P Q = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & n \\
0 & 2m & 0 \\
n & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Finally, we take a diagonal matrix $R,$
$$
R = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
m & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -n & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -n
\end{array}
\right).
$$
We reach
$$
R^T Q^T P^T H P Q R = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -m n^2 \\
0 & 2mn^2 & 0 \\
-m n^2 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \; \; = \; \;  m n^2 \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

That is, $f$ represents an integer multiple of $y^2 - zx.$ Let us call that $N(y^2 - z x),$ so this $N = m n^2.$

The matrix entries I came up with for the general case may be  much larger than required. On page 28, Cassels asks about $3 x^2 - 2 y^2 - z^2.$ I have a computer program to find these expressions with small numbers. I will not bother doubling the diagonal entries,

%  jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./homothety_indef 3 -2 -1 0 0 0    0 -24 0 0 24 0    4

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 2 & -2 \\
0 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & -1 \\
-2 & 4 & 1
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 12 \\
0 & -24 & 0 \\
12 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
That is,
$$ \langle 3,-2,-1,0,0,0 \rangle $$ represents
$$ \langle 0, -24,0,0,24,0 \rangle $$ or
$$ -24 \cdot \langle 0, 1,0,0,-1,0 \rangle. $$

This shows the six Pythagorean Triple type parametrizations needed for
$$  66 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - 115(yz + zx + xy) =0 $$
The first matrix means
$$ x = 120 u^2 + 229 uv + 118 v^2; \; \; y = 118 u^2 + 7 u v + 9 v^2; \; \; z = 9 u^2 + 11 u v + 120 v^2. $$ This is up to order (lots of symmetry) and negating all three $xyz.$ $u,v$ are not required of the same $\pm$ sign. Indeed, we rename and negate so that $x \geq |y| \geq |z|.$ Otherwise many more recipes (such matrices) might be needed. Oh, there is something very unusual caused by the extreme symmetry for this problem: in all cases, we may demand $u,v \geq 0.$ Rare behavior. The other oddity, that we always get $x,y,z \geq 0,$ is simply that $2 \cdot 66 > 115,$ and says only that the null cone happens to lie entirely inside the positive octant (and the negative octant).

========================================

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
? x = 120 * u^2 + 229 * u * v + 118 * v^2 
%1 = 120*u^2 + 229*v*u + 118*v^2
? 
? y = 118 * u^2 + 7 * u * v + 9 * v^2 
%2 = 118*u^2 + 7*v*u + 9*v^2
? 
? z = 9 * u^2 + 11 * u * v + 120 * v^2 
%3 = 9*u^2 + 11*v*u + 120*v^2
? 66 * ( x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - 115 * ( y * z + z * x + x * y)
%4 = 0
?
```

=========================================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./isotropy 66 115

 A = 66       B = 115

    120    229    118
    118      7      9
      9     11    120

    129    227    108
    108    -11     10
     10     31    129

    145    211     84
     84    -43     18
     18     79    145

    150    199     73
     73    -53     24
     24    101    150

    153    187     64
     64    -59     30
     30    119    153

    154    181     60
     60    -61     33
     33    127    154


  end of  A = 66       B = 115


=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

===================================================

```
    120    118      9      < 120, 229, 118 >      1  0    
    129    108     10      < 129, 227, 108 >      1  0    
    145     84     18      < 145, 211, 84 >      1  0    
    150     73     24      < 150, 199, 73 >      1  0    
    153     64     30      < 153, 187, 64 >      1  0    
    154     60     33      < 154, 181, 60 >      1  0    
    395    314     32      < 154, 181, 60 >      1  1    
    404    302     35      < 153, 187, 64 >      1  1    
    422    275     44      < 150, 199, 73 >      1  1    
    440    242     59      < 145, 211, 84 >      1  1    
    464    170    107      < 129, 227, 108 >      1  1    
    467    140    134      < 120, 229, 118 >      1  1    
    880    783     66      < 153, 187, 64 >      1  2    
   1038    540    151      < 154, 181, 60 >      2  1    
   1056    495    178      < 120, 229, 118 >      2  1    
   1086    375    268      < 145, 211, 84 >      2  1    
   1764   1290    157      < 153, 187, 64 >      1  3    
   1782   1264    165      < 129, 227, 108 >      1  3    
   1800   1237    174      < 154, 181, 60 >      1  3    
   1869   1122    220      < 120, 229, 118 >      1  3    
   2020    669    522      < 150, 199, 73 >      3  1    
   2022    645    544      < 145, 211, 84 >      3  1    
   2310   2211    172      < 153, 187, 64 >      2  3    
   2602   1851    240      < 145, 211, 84 >      2  3    
   2654   2333    200      < 145, 211, 84 >      1  4    
   2712   1675    306      < 154, 181, 60 >      3  2    
   2836   1422    435      < 150, 199, 73 >      3  2    
   2916   1182    595      < 120, 229, 118 >      2  3    
   2924   1973    290      < 120, 229, 118 >      1  4    
   2955    946    792      < 129, 227, 108 >      3  2    
   3005   1838    344      < 154, 181, 60 >      1  4    
   3260   1109    818      < 153, 187, 64 >      4  1
```

========================================================

Answer (score 1):

One standard construction of $L^2$ is to start from a space of
square-integrable functions, which is only positive semidefinite
(and thus contains many isotropic vectors), and form the quotient by
the kernel of the inner product (which consists of those isotropic vectors).
Of course $L^2$ is the arena for much important mathematics, 
both pure and applied.